# Angular 6 - value in textarea showing as Object Object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular6

I have some data stored using localstorage and saved using stringify and I want to add the data to a textarea.

Here are the code parts:

```
{
  "name":"some name"
}
```

To get is I'm doing this:

```
this.mydat = localStorage.getItem('mydata');
```

I have this in the localstorage in a variable called mydata

So a console log to this.mydat will give me this:

```
{
  "name":"some name"
}
```

Now I want to add this to the textarea, so I'm doing this:

```
this.con.nativeElement.value = JSON.parse(this.mydat);
```

This shows as:

```
[object Object]
```

on the Textarea.

What I want to see is something like this:

```
{
    name : 'some name'

}
```

On my textarea I've added the json pipe:

```
{{ thecontents | json }}
```

So in theory it should show a js object?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try this: this.obj = JSON.parse(this.mydat); console.log(this.obj) and in html {{this.obj | json}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are passing a Json object to the text field if you want to display the string

do Json.stringify(you data) and then pass it to your text field

Comment: I tried that but but it shows as json and not as js object

Comment: JSON.stringify(myData, undefined, 4); try this

Comment: js object can't be displayed in  a text field unless they are converted into string but if you only want to show it in a nice way other than the normla one line json string you can use the above code

Comment: I tried the code above but the textarea is showing backslashes ("{\"name\":\"some name )

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gojoxesero/edit?html,css,js,output works fine here can you post what are you trying now

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the object,

```
this.mydat =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mydata'));
```

and then

```
{{ mydat | json }}
```